# Office fails to load in Outlook web plugin for IOS only

Tags: ios, outlook-web-addins

In my plugin I implemented sign in functionality with outlook dialog API. 
It loads a credentials form (not in my control) with a back url. The sign in response correctly comes at my node server and I see that the user is authenticated. There on the server, an ejs file is prepared and is sent to client. Back on the client I want to execute messageParent, so I can close the dialog. **This works in browsers (including safari), android, desktop and etc, it's working in Outlook for MAC but doesn't work on iOS.** Sample code following:

in nodejs:

```
app.post("/auth/:token", (req, res) => {
    console.log('auth return url logic', req.params.token, JSON.stringify(req.body));

    let send_response = function(res, user) {
        try {
            return res.render(
                'send_to_parent.ejs',
                {user : user},
                function (e, r) {
                    try {
                        res.end(r);
                    }
                    catch(e) {}
                } 
            );
        }
        catch (err) {
             console.log(1312312321, err);
        }
    };

    send_response(res, {});
});
```

in send_to_parent.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>#Sign in</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         console.log('in ejs');

         function messageParent() {
              console.log('message parent');
              Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);
         }

         function openClick() {
              window.setTimeout(messageParent, 100);
         }

         Office.initialize = function (reason) {
             console.log('office initialize');
             $(document)
                .ready(function () {
                     console.log('jquery ready');
                     openClick();
                 });
          };
     </script>
 </head>
```

Any ideas what is wrong or how to diagnose?

=====EDIT=====
Well, in order to debug I made a few code changes and replacements. Now my code in ejs file is looking like that:

```
<head>
   <title>#Sign in</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Authorization Successful</h1>
    <div id="log">test</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById("log").innerText += "before initialize";
       Office.initialize = function () {
          document.getElementById("log").innerText += "initialized";
          $(document)
              .ready(function () {
                  document.getElementById("log").innerText += "jquery";

                  $("#closeButton").click(function () {
                    document.getElementById("log").innerText += "close clicked";
                    Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);
                });

                Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);
            });
      };

   </script>
</body>
```

After successful login my log div is only getting updated with "before initialize", which means that Office.initialize never happens. I also tried to call jquery.ready first and this proved that jquery is working fine. For some reason Office does not want to initialize. Why's that?

====SECOND EDIT====
Digging further into the problem I made a several changes.

```
function log(text) {
    document.getElementById("log").innerText += text;
}

function messageParent() {
    log('message parent');
    try {
        if ( !Office ) {
            log('no_office');
        }
        else if (!Office.context ) {
            log('no_context')
        }
        else if( !Office.context.ui) {
            log('no_ui');
        }
        else if (!Office.context.ui.messageParent) {
            log('no_message');
        }

        Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);
    }
    catch(e) {
        log("error");
        log(e);
    }
}

log("here");
Office.onReady ( function (reason) {
    log('office initialize');
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            log('jquery ready');
            // messageParent();

            $("#closeButton").click(function () {
                log(" close_clicked_out_of_office ");
                debugger
                messageParent();
            });
        });
});
```

Now at last I have Outlook. I also have Outlook.context , but no ui. So I can't execute messageParent.